# How to avoid JSONObject Null check

Tags: java, json, null

I have JSON like below

```
{
  "a1": "aaa",
  "b1": 333,
  "c1": {
    "c1": "ccc",
    "d1": "ddd",
    "f1": [
      {"a1": "xyz"},
      {"b1":  "lmn"},
      {"c1":123.00}
    ]
  }
}
```

I am reading the file into String and creating a JSONObject as below

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(str));
```

The JSON is coming to my application from outside so the content can be very different in times. Say it can be completely null or some of the elements can be null or array size can be 0 or 1 or more etc.

When I am working on the JSONObject I can keep on checking all the elements using

```
json.has and !=null
```

so that it does not throw any exception.

I can have the code as below

```
if(
      json.has("c") 
   && json.getJSONObject("c")!= null 
   && json.getJSONObject("c").has("f") 
   && json.getJSONObject("c").getJSONArray("f").length() > 1 
   &&json.getJSONObject("c").getJSONArray("f").getJSONObject(1).has("b")
  ){     
      String x = json.getJSONObject("c").getJSONArray("f").getJSONObject(1).getString("b");
   }
```

That makes the code having a long list of if conditions.

However I am thinking instead I can just enclose the statement with try catch

```
try {
     String x = json.getJSONObject("c").getJSONArray("f").getJSONObject(1).getString("b");
    }catch(JSONException e) {
        //log and proceed
    }
```

Please suggest if there is any valid reason in this case to put a long if conditions rather than just try - catch - log and proceed.

Also can you share if using JSONException has any "pros" in this context ?

Comment: What language is this? Is this Java?

Comment: @Amy Yes it is Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 0: Long If-Statement

I think this is far too convoluted, especially as the chain gets longer. The only case where I would consider a remotely similar solution is if the user needs to know exactly at which point the problem lies and there are specific guidelines on how to solve this and how this may occur in a very specific use case, however in that case you need a large number of if statements and log statements.

### Option 1: Try-Catch

Try-catch, as you suggested, is indeed possible, however you need to make sure that you catch all possible exceptions that can occur when a JSON field is not present or of the wrong type, for example ClassCastException and NullPointerException. It is short but not very elegant and as the other answerer said might hide other exceptions (but you could still log the stack trace).

### Option 2: Java 8 Optional

Another option is to find a library that allows you to use the Java 8 Optional type. For example, this is suggested using [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-optional). This is more elegant but could become a large chain as well. Also this adds one more dependency to your project.

### Option 3: Path Expressions

A third option would be to use path expression [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), where you can put all your statements into one expression and get all results for that. In my opinion this is the perfect use case and by far the best solution. The only downside is that this adds one more dependency to your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I keep a null check for json object itself I think JSONException should be catching all possible issues that I was checking otherwise in the if conditions. Please share what you opine. I will check 2 and 3 - thank you for sharing.

Comment: @ctimus: I think option 3 is by far the most elegant one, I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried option 3 as follows:
String a1 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.c.f[0].a");
however I still need to enclose this statement within PathNotFoundException which does not take care of ClassCastException. However JSONException catches this and shows a proper message. I still feel that for the scenario that I have described, only catching JSONException should catch all the issues which I otherwise was putting into if condition to tackle. In case there is any other exception that may occur, then that would also happen in long-if option as well.

Comment: I have tried json path with Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS and it is doing what I wanted however (1) this takes lot of time compared to using option 0 and 1 (2) it is showing a log DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path for each read - not sure if the time it takes is because of that. So JSONPath seems to be not that effective. Anything I need to do differently ?

Comment: @ctimus: You're welcome! If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: @ctimus: How much time does it need and which machine are you using? Did you make sure to follow good benchmark practices?

Comment: For the load 1000000 (running a loop) and retrieving a JSONPath (7 level depth) value from a JSON (14k lines)

(It took 173 ms using usual getJSONObject and memory 0 MB)
(It took 28298 ms using JSONPath and memory 2 MB)

System - 
macOS 10.14.6
2.9 GHz Intel Core i9

Answer (score 1):

> Please suggest if there is any valid reason in this case to put a long if conditions rather than just try - catch - log and proceed.

Here are a couple of reasons:

- Efficiency: creating, throwing and catching an exception is relatively expensive.  Exactly how expensive is version dependent, and probably context dependent too.  In recent versions, the JIT compiler can (AFAIK) optimize some sequences into a conditional branch.  However, if you are going to log the exception, then the JVM is going to have to create an exception object and populate the stacktrace, and that this the most expensive part.
- If you log `NullPointerException` for:

  ```
  json.getJSONObject("c").getJSONArray("f").getJSONObject(1).getString("b")
  ```

  you *may not* be able to tell which of the components was missing or null.  The line number in the stacktrace won't be sufficient to distinguish the cases.  (With a `JSONException` the exception message will give you more clues.)
- You also can't distinguish the case where `json` is `null`, which is probably a different kind of problem; i.e. a bug.  If you treat that as a data error, you are making it difficult to find and fix the code bug.
- If you catch *all* exceptions (as suggested by another answer), you are potentially hiding more classes of bugs.  Bad idea.

---

> Also can you share if using JSONException has any "pros" in this context ?

The only real "pro" is that it is possibly less code, especially if you can put the *try ... catch* around a lot of this code.

The bottom line is that you need to weigh this up for yourself.  And one factor is how likely it is that you will get JSON that doesn't match your code's expectations.  That will depend in part on what is producing the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the responses above, below is how the problem has been solved.

[JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) is working the best for the scenario I mentioned. Thanks to @Konrad.

First create a configuration object of type *com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration*

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).mappingProvider(new JsonOrgMappingProvider()).jsonProvider(new JsonOrgJsonProvider()).build();
```

- **Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS** - This will help to suppress the exception in case an element is missing
- ***mappingProvider(new JsonOrgMappingProvider()).jsonProvider(new JsonOrgJsonProvider()*** - This uses the right provider so that when we parse the json we don't need to convert the JSONObject to String thus giving optimal performance.

```
DocumentContext docContext = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json);
```

If we use default provider then we need to parse the JSONObject as follows

```
DocumentContext docContext = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json.toString());
```

Then to read the element I used

```
docContext.read("$.a.b.c.d.values[0].e.f")
```

The performance is now optimal as well. The reason it was taking more time and memory was because

- I was reading and parsing at the same time in a loop. Later on I moved the parsing out of loop.
- I was using default provider and was doing json.toString()